# Sending a Json from an android app to a local db

Tags: java, android, json, database, gradle

I'm creating an android app for sending json files to a local db I've created. But, whenever I try to start it, my gradle sync fails. I set everything right in the right spot (I think), but I don't know why.
Here's my gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "francesco.postjson"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'
    compile 'cz.msebera.android:httpclient:4.4.1.1'
    compile files('libs/httpcore-4.4.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/okhttp-3.4.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/commons-codec-1.9.jar')
    compile files('libs/commons-logging-1.2.jar')
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.0.0'
    compile files('libs/httpclient-win-4.5.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpclient-4.5.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpcore-4.4.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/fluent-hc-4.5.2.jar')
}
```

I'm using those types of dependencies and I'm having the error:

```
Error:(25, 0) Could not find method classpath() for arguments [com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
<a href="openFile:C:\Users\Francesco\AndroidStudioProjects\POSTJSON\app\build.gradle">Open File</a>
```

Do I have to place the dependencies in another place? Thank you

Edit: here's my code for sending

```
package francesco.postjson;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.Activity;
import francesco.postjson.Person;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    TextView tvIsConnected;
    EditText etName,etCountry,etTwitter;
    Button btnPost;

    Person person;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // get reference to the views
        tvIsConnected = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvIsConnected);
        etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);
        etCountry = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etCountry);
        etTwitter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etTwitter);
        btnPost = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPost);

        // check if you are connected or not
        if(isConnected()){
            tvIsConnected.setBackgroundColor(0xFF00CC00);
            tvIsConnected.setText("You are conncted");
        }
        else{
            tvIsConnected.setText("You are NOT conncted");
        }

        // add click listener to Button "POST"
        btnPost.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    public static String POST(String url, Person person){
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        String result = "";
        try {

            // 1. create HttpClient
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            // 2. make POST request to the given URL
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            String json = "";

            // 3. build jsonObject
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            jsonObject.accumulate("name", person.getName());
            jsonObject.accumulate("country", person.getCountry());
            jsonObject.accumulate("twitter", person.getTwitter());

            // 4. convert JSONObject to JSON to String
            json = jsonObject.toString();

            // ** Alternative way to convert Person object to JSON string usin Jackson Lib
            // ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            // json = mapper.writeValueAsString(person);

            // 5. set json to StringEntity
            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json);

            // 6. set httpPost Entity
            httpPost.setEntity(se);

            // 7. Set some headers to inform server about the type of the content
            httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

            // 8. Execute POST request to the given URL
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);

            // 9. receive response as inputStream
            inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

            // 10. convert inputstream to string
            if(inputStream != null)
                result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
            else
                result = "Did not work!";

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }

        // 11. return result
        return result;
    }

    public boolean isConnected(){
        ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Activity.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected())
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        switch(view.getId()){
            case R.id.btnPost:
                if(!validate())
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Enter some data!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                // call AsynTask to perform network operation on separate thread
                new HttpAsyncTask().execute("http://hmkcode.appspot.com/jsonservlet");
                break;
        }

    }
    private class HttpAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

            person = new Person();
            person.setName(etName.getText().toString());
            person.setCountry(etCountry.getText().toString());
            person.setTwitter(etTwitter.getText().toString());

            return POST(urls[0],person);
        }
        // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Data Sent!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    private boolean validate(){
        if(etName.getText().toString().trim().equals(""))
            return false;
        else if(etCountry.getText().toString().trim().equals(""))
            return false;
        else if(etTwitter.getText().toString().trim().equals(""))
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
    private static String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException{
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String line = "";
        String result = "";
        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
            result += line;

        inputStream.close();
        return result;

    }
}
```

Comment: If you are using windows then its better to put your projects on some other directories as window tries to protect C drive. The issue could be  org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler cannot access build file due to security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, share part of your code where you send JSON.

Second, why do you use so many dependencies? Maybe you are trying to use Apache classes, and found somewhere in the internet these dependencies. Total solution can be provided after you post your code. But try to remove this line: `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'`. And use HttpURLConnection instead of Apache classes, because last are deprecated.

(I know that this must be a comment, but I have low reputation).

Comment: edited. Also i tried removing all of those, but i can't use it either

Comment: You have over 50 reputation, so you should be able to comment on questions, Turkhan.

Answer (score 0):

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'
```

It should be given in your project gradle file, not in module gradle file.

For apache http clients use, add

`useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'`

inside the android tag in module gradle i. e after

```
buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"
```

Comment: now i removed that file, and can't find all of the httpclient, httppost, ecc ecc in my code. How do i solve this?